# Convert varbinary(max) column from Azure SQL database into local image file

Tags: azure, image, azure-sql-database, varbinarymax

We have an Azure SQL database with a table which contains a number of images in a varbinary(max) column. I would like to be able to extract these to image files to be stored locally.

I have found various posts and code snippets for doing this from a SQL Server database, but they all involve running sp_configure to change the permissions for 'show advanced options' and 'OLE automation procedures' which don't apply to Azure SQL.

Is there a way of doing this from Azure?

Many thanks!
Jim

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem. I brief list of solutions:

1. Use [SSIS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2693/export-images-from-a-sql-server-table-to-a-folder-with-ssis/) or ADF.
2. [Export](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2dbRZL_fltg) the Azure SQL Database from Azure to a SQL Server On Prem, use `sp_configure`, and then delete the varbinary(max) column that contains the images on Azure.

Comment: Thanks Francesco. I am not sure we will have a local SQL Server available, so I might have to look at getting SSIS implemented.

Is this the only other option? No way of doing this directly from the Azure SQL db?

Comment: Install SQL Server Developer edition on your laptop and do it there